# I am the real mcc (Riddle)

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My crimson frame is ever so slick,
>
> with a stimulant swish I might give you a kick.
>
> My number 13 shell might give you a chill,
>
> don't over use me because I'm a real heart-kill.

**WHAT AM I?**

BONUS RHYME:

> Some might say that I'm quite extreme, they're probably right my species is mean.

HINT:

> Maybe i'll give you a chill because I'm often chilled...

Comment: Hi I'm new to the puzzles exchange, do I only give the answer when someone has answered correctly?

Comment: You will most likely get answers soon, you will then be able to confirm or infirm the propositions. If you don't get answers for a day, you can then post hints toward finding the answer (it usually can go up to 5 hints). If even then no one find the answer, then you can provide it yourself.

Comment: is it related to a game?

Comment: Am I allowed to say? @WeShall

Comment: no give aways, but cryptic clues help :) i would suggest look at some puzzles that has high views or multiple answers from other puzzlers, that might help you form a better understanding

Comment: You can have that bonus hint :) @WeShall

Comment: The `number 13 shell` makes me think of [electron shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_shell).

Comment: Ohhhhh very close, I'd roll with that sort of idea @EngineerToast

Comment: If you work that bit out, it's still only one piece of the puzzle ;) @EngineerToast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> Red Bull? The one that gives you wings?

My crimson frame is ever so slick,

> Red can.

with a stimulant swish I might give you a kick.

> Gives you energy. Caffeine is a stimulant and a bull might kick you.

My number 13 shell might give you a chill,

> So, this was tricky, but EngineerToast got it rolling with aluminum can which is in the Boron (13) group and the aluminum itself is cold.

don't over use me because I'm a real heart-kill.

> Too much Red Bull and you'll probably die... lol.  Too much caffeine could damage your heart.

Some might say that I'm quite extreme, they're probably right my species is mean.

> Red Bull sponsors a lot of extreme sports, a bull is considered aggressive.

I didn't get the title, but it's clever.

> Per Cutter, MCC is another way of writing MC^2 as in E = MC^2 or *energy* and Red Bull is an energy drink.

Comment: Bingo! We have a winner

Comment: Nice, I'll fill in the clues.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've done it. You can say which ones you go though

Answer (score 1):

Are you...

> **Alienware 13**

My crimson frame is ever so slick,

> The gaming machine in red is definitely slick

With a stimulant swish I might give you a kick.

> The hustling sound when it boots up gives gamers a kick

My number 13 shell might give you a chill,

> This might be referring to the cover with a chilling 'Alien' themed shell

Don't over use me because I'm a real heart-kill.

> No extreme gaming. Not good for your heart in long term.

And MCC is...

> Mission Control Center

Comment: It kinda fits, but no. Trust me the answer fits every line perfectly. Good answer though!